# Prepared statements against a JSON key throwing "must appear in the GROUP BY clause" in PostgreSQL using PDO

Tags: php, json, postgresql, group-by

I am trying to dynamically group by json keys to find the average answer.

```
select
   tbl.data->>'Example' as response,
   count(tbl.data->>'Example') as total
from table tbl
group by tbl.data->>'Example'
order by total
limit 1
```

This Query works fine when it is ran inside PostgreSQL and I get my expected result:

```
|     response   |  total  |
|--------------------------|
|  Hello World   |    4    |
```

The issue now occurs when I don't know the keys. They're dynamically created and thus I need to loop over them.

```
$sql = <<<END
    select
       tbl.data->>? as response,
       count(tbl.data->>?) as total
    from table tbl
    group by tbl.data->>?
    order by total
    limit 1
END;

$stmt = (new \PDO(...))->Prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array_fill(1, 3, 'Example'));
$stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

'Example' comes from user input. The JSON is created by the user, the keys could be anything. In this case, its hard-coded but I run a seperate SQL query to get all the keys and loop over them:

But I always get the following error:

> tbl.data must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Now, I assume this is because of the prepared statement treating the column as data but this information derives from user input so I need to use prepared statements.

```
select json_object_keys(data) as keys from table
```

Any guess to how I can resolve this?

Comment: This is not different from taking table or column names from user input. Prepared statements can't solve this because they're designed to do the exact opposite: keep code and data apart. I suspect you'll need to do some white-listing and string manipulation.

Comment: I've thought about whitelisting but again, the json keys derive from user input. I can manipulate the string but nothing is safer than using prepared statements. Should I proceed with attempting to strip anything bad out? @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Unfortunately, prepared statements aren't a tool to generate safe dynamic code. As far as I know you don't have a builtin tool for that. Stripping bad things is a black-list approach. Accepting a few good values is feasible, rejecting every conceivable bad value anyone could ever image is not.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @ÁlvaroGonzález - I guess the issue is that it is so dynamic and perhaps I should do this away from SQL and inside the code

Comment: Have you tried using named placeholders rather than `?`, where the 1st and 3rd use the same placeholder name?  That is the only way for this to be valid (and I can't test it on php, so maybe it is broken there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Php. But from this link(https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/postgres-stored-procedure-call-in-php-1475), seems it's pretty ok to use functions in php.

[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0f8750da33bb1c96a4557c98ecbdc82a)

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_answer (_key text)
    RETURNS json
    AS $$
DECLARE
    is_exists boolean;
    _sql text;
    _return json;
BEGIN
    _sql := $sql$
    SELECT
        row_to_json(cte.*)
    FROM (
        SELECT
            tbl.data ->> $1 AS response,
            count(tbl.data ->> $1) AS total
        FROM
            tbl
        GROUP BY
            1
        ORDER BY
            total DESC
        LIMIT 1) cte $sql$;
    SELECT
        (data[_key] IS NULL) INTO is_exists
    FROM
        tbl;
    IF is_exists THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION '% not exists.', _key;
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE '% sql', _sql;
        EXECUTE _sql
        USING _key INTO _return;
        RETURN _return;
    END IF;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

then call it. `select * from find_answer('example');`

---

about Prepared statements

> Prepared statements only last for the duration of the **current**
> **database session**. When the session ends, the prepared statement is
> forgotten, so it must be recreated before being used again. This also
> means that a single prepared statement cannot be used by multiple
> simultaneous database clients; however, each client can create their
> own prepared statement to use. Prepared statements can be manually
> cleaned up using the DEALLOCATE command.